# Calculate prorated amount in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to join table A with B & get the prorated sales amount.
How to achieve this . Can anyone help me?

```
Table A:
SALES_TIME_PERIOD_ID    CODE    ID  FLOOR_NO    UNIT_NO
31/07/2015               CN     K1A    L01        153
31/08/2015               CN     K1A    L01        153
30/09/2015               CN     K1A    L01        153
31/10/2015               CN     K1A    L01        153
30/11/2015               CN     K1A    L01        153
31/12/2015               CN     K1A    L01        153
31/01/2016               CN     K1A    L01        153
29/02/2016               CN     K1A    L01        153
31/03/2016               CN     K1A    L01        153
30/04/2016               CN     K1A    L01        153
31/05/2016               CN     K1A    L01        153
30/06/2016               CN     K1A    L01        153

Table B:

CODE    ID  FLOORNO UNITNO  CHARGESTARTDATE CHARGEENDDATE   PERIODICAMOUNT
CN      K1A  L01    153         24/08/2014  23/08/2015      13400.96
CN      K1A  L01    153         24/08/2015  23/08/2016      14071
CN      K1A  L01    153         24/08/2016  23/08/2017      14774.55
```

I Want output as:

```
SALES_TIME_PERIOD_ID    CODE    ID  FLOOR_NO    UNIT_NO ACTUAL      PRORATED
31/07/2015               CN     K1A   L01       153     13400.96    13400.96
31/08/2015               CN     K1A   L01       153     13400.96    13573.87355
30/09/2015               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
31/10/2015               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
30/11/2015               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
31/12/2015               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
31/01/2016               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
29/02/2016               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
31/03/2016               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
30/04/2016               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
31/05/2016               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
30/06/2016               CN     K1A   L01       153     14071       14071
```

Comment: Just inner join, perhaps... with some conditions... you need to show some effort and elaborate on the business case here. what's the dates in table b mean? how is the data related... based on the ID or ID and CODE or...?

Comment: We can join based on id, code, floor, unit no.i need the periodic amount which falls between the sales time period id & if there is any increase or decrease it should show as prorated

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
tableA.SALES_TIME_PERIOD_ID
, tableA.Code
, tableA.ID
, tableA.floor_no
, tableA.Unit_no
, cast(tableB.PERIODICAMOUNT as decimal(13,2)) as ACTUAL
, tableB.PERIODICAMOUNT  as PRORATED


from tableA

inner join tableB
on tableA.Code = tableB.Code
and tableA.ID = tableB.ID
and tableA.floorno - tableB.floorno
and tableA.unitno = tableB.unitno
and tableA.SALES_TIME_PERIOD_ID between tableB.CHARGESTARTDATE and tableB.CHARGEENDDATE
```

I have made a lot of assumptions here of course.. but this should get you going!

Comment: This will join Table A & B. But how to get the prorated amount?

Comment: That depends on your business definition of what "Prorated Amount" actually means.. and how it is sourced..

Comment: Table A has sales time period which is always EOM. Table B has charge start & end date. I need to calculate prorated on the basis of dates, Eg. For the month of august 2015 periodic amount changes on 23rd. So need to use formula as below: (23/31*13400.96)+(8/31*14071)=13573.87355

Comment: Once you have joined the tables.. you have access to all the dates that you need for calculation.. not sure if this is the correct way to do it.. but one way to do it could be
23 = datepart(day,CHARGEENDDATE)
31 = datepart(day,SALES_TIME_PERIOD_ID)
8 = datepart(month,CHARGEENDDATE)

this should give you enough to work out how to use this in the formula within the select statement..